# MWPhotoBrowser will not display photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, mwphotobrowser

I'm trying to implement MWPhotoBrowser in my project. I've added all the delegates, but it still will not display the photo.

Here's my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MWPhotoBrowserSegue" sender:self] 
}
```

This is my segue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MWPhotoBorwserSegue"]) 
   {
       photoBrowser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc]initWithDelegate:self]; 
       UINavigationController * nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:photoBrowser]; 

      nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDisolve; 

      [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picasa.jpg"]]; 

      [photoBrowser setCurrentPhotoIndex:0]; 

      [self.navigationController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil]; 
   }
}
```

The #ofPhotosInBrowser:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser 
{
    return self.photos.count;
}
```

photoAtIndex:

```
- (MWPhoto *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
if (index < self.photos.count)
    return [self.photos objectAtIndex:index];
return nil;
}
```

Here's what I get after the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is called: 
[image]
**Edit for Solution:**

MWPhotoBrowser will not display a photo unless you put self.title in the initWithStyle: method. I also forgot to add the viewWillDisappear and viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to call reload data on it. Check Mwphotobrowser.h for proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self presentViewController:yourNewNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];